Converting from integer value to array not returning the correct, original values
I have a C# application where I am saving off my array into an integer value, which is working.
here is my array: int[] myArray = { 0, 1, 3, 15 };
However, when I try to convert myArray to see what values it has it returns the following {1, 3, 1, 5} as you can see it doesn't get the 0, and it separates the 15 into {1, 5}.
Here is my approach:
double[] array = { 0, 1, 3, 15 };

var result = string.Concat(array);


int resultNumber = int.Parse(result); // returns 1315

int[] resultToArray = resultNumber.ToString().Select(o => Convert.ToInt32(o) - 48).ToArray();

What am I missing from my resultToArray?

Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
It is unclear what you are asking or what the problem is.
Please [edit] your question to include a more detailed description of the problem you have. How would you know how to split a number like 12345 to the original array? There are no indicators you can use.

The zero is dropped because it's a leading zero: 01315 == 1315. Regardless, there's no way signify where one number starts and to with a normal integer, you're much better off writing the numbers to a string rather than to an integer:
using System.Linq;

// Convert array to string
int[] array = { 0, 1, 3, 15 };
string asString = string.Join(',', array); // -> "0,1,3,15"

// Convert string to array
int[] array2 = asString.Split(',')
    .Select(int.Parse)
    .ToArray();


If you have to store the numbers into an integer, you can pack smaller numbers into the bigger one. Note that you'll be limited in both the range of numbers AND the total numbers you can support. In this example code, there's a max of four bytes (0-255):
byte[] array = {0, 1, 3, 15};

// Pack these bytes into the int. Max: 4 numbers.
int result = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) {
    result |= (array[i] << (8 * i));
}
// result -> 251855104


// Retrieve the packed bytes
byte[] array2 = new byte[4];
for (int i = 0; i < array2.Length; i++) {
    array2[i] = (byte) ((result >> (8 * i)) & 0xFF);
}
// array2 -> [0, 1, 3, 15];

